# Refresh token validation with upstream IdP

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml, identityserver3, ws-federation

Let's say I have my own IdP, using IdentityServer3, but for some customers, I need to delegate authentication to another IdP, so that they can use their main AD credentials. At the same time, I don't want to use the other IdP as the direct authority for my applications, because there are certain workflows built in to the login process that I need to preserve. The solution seems to be to use the other IdP as an upstream IdP on the backend of my IdP.

```
                  /--> My AD
                 /---> IdentityServer3 --SAML----> Okta -----> Customer AD
Client --> API ------> IdentityServer3 --WS-Fed--> AzureAD <-> Customer AD
  \-------------/
```

On the front end of my IdP I'm using (among other things) OAuth2 with the Auth Code flow. I have the requirement to be able to support long-lived refresh tokens (months). During login, if the user types in a domain that belongs to another IdP, they will get redirected to the appropriate login page (e.g. at Microsoft). When I receive a successful authentication ticket from the upstream IdP, I issue new tokens from my IdP to the client. As the access token expires, the client can come back for a new one for as long as the refresh token is good.

Here is the problem: What if the user is deactivated/deleted in the customer AD (employee fired?) before the refresh token expires? I shouldn't issue new access tokens to them. When I'm not using an upstream IdP, I can simply check the AD record. Is there anything I can do when I have an upstream IdP, or some other authentication setup that would make more sense for these requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Identity providers simply allow / deny authentication. If they deny it, they don't provide a reason for security.

The best way would be to access the external parties' repository if that is possible.

You could use the OAuth resource owner password flow under the hood (not very secure though). Here you include the user name and password in the message. If it succeeds, renew. If it doesn't, don't.

Comment: Unfortunately, accessing the external party's repository defeats the purpose of using standard auth protocols, unless it can be done through standard auth protocols, which is what I was hoping for. I have confirmed the resource owner password flow works with Azure AD, so you are correct that it would work. I really don't want to be in the business of storing user passwords though, so I'm thinking I need to implement validation of upstream refresh tokens when validating downstream refresh tokens in the IdP.